# Mystery Sound on my Macbook - Triggers every 3-5 Minutes!

Tags: audio, bug

Weiiird problem.

Every 3-6 minutes something is triggering my computer's text-to-speech to say the word "nut." I have zero programs running in the background, I know it is internal because I can see the task operating when I used a `sudo fs_usage` (screenshot)

How can I find what's causing this sound? I previously fixed this problem by deleting all my system's voice files — but after an update to Mojave the sound files are back and so is the ghost sound.

I can provide any system reports/files you need but you'll likely have to walk me through the necessary commands, etc.

Side note: I'm the co-creator of [The Nut Button](https://www.thenutbutton.com/), so more likely than not someone is messin' around and got this bug on my laptop.

[image: you can see the Alex Compact voice triggering]

Comment: here's a video of when it happens with activity terminal open and fs_usage running

https://streamable.com/4ngey

Comment: Check all crontabs on the system and all the `launchd` scheduled jobs (for users and system). Likely the call to `/usr/bin/say` is coming from a scheduled job running on the system. See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/126907/how-can-i-get-a-script-to-run-every-day-on-mac-os-x) for all the ways jobs can be scheduled on an OS X machine.

Answer (score 2):

wow yup thank you @Ian C. there was a scheduled crontab. I used `crontab -l` to list all schedueled tasks and `crontab -r` to remove them

thanks! [image]